# Sort by data from multiple columns

Tags: sql, pdo

For customer reviews on my products, I have them stored in SQL something like the below:

```
    durability | cost | appearance
  ----------------------------------
        5      |  3   |     4
        2      |  4   |     2
        1      |  5   |     5
```

Each value is an out of five score in the three categories.

When I want to print this information on page, I'd like to order them in descending order by the average score of an individual review.

```
SELECT *
    FROM reviews
    ORDER BY (durability+cost+appearance)/3 DESC
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but is there a way to get my result? I don't want to include an `average` column in SQL because outside of this one small application, it serves zero purpose.

Comment: put ORDER BY, not SORT BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` instead of `SORT BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM reviews
ORDER BY (durability+cost+appearance)/3 DESC
```

**EDIT:**

To see the order by value, try adding one more column in the select clause:

```
SELECT *,(durability+cost+appearance)/3 as OrderValue
FROM reviews
ORDER BY (durability+cost+appearance)/3 DESC
```

Sample output:

```
DURABILITY  COST    APPEARANCE  ORDERVALUE
5           3       4           4
1           5       5           3
2           4       2           2
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a flub on my part. I meant to type `ORDER BY`. Regardless, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @riista: I have checked. It is working for me. See the **edit** in my answer.

Comment: @riista: With ORDER BY now, I see no reason for this not to work. What problem do you have with it?